# Mifare Plus SE 1K card Personalization

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I'm completely new to NFC and trying to learn what it can offer. 
So coming to question I have few Mifare plus SE 1K cards. I am trying to personalize by switching from SL0 to SL3 using TapLinx SDK (if you have better SDK for android please suggest so).

I've successfully switched from SL0 to SL1 using below code:

```
 plusSL0.writePerso(0x9000, KEY_AES128); //master key
                plusSL0.writePerso(0x9001, KEY_AES128); // config key
                plusSL0.writePerso(0x9003, KEY_AES128); //SL3 switch key
                plusSL0.commitPerso();
```

and when switching from SL1 to SL3 using below code :

```
 plusSL1.switchToSL3(objKEY_AES128);
```

It gives me an error :

```
 com.nxp.nfclib.exceptions.SecurityException: data not block size aligned
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing personalization of cards. If anyone can guild me correct direction that'd be helpful!